# preprocess_input() method in keras

Tags: python, keras

I am trying out some sample `keras` code from [this `keras` documentation page](https://keras.io/applications/)

What does the `preprocess_input(x)` function of `keras` module do in the code below? Why do we have to do `expand_dims(x, axis=0)` before that is passed to the `preprocess_input()` method?

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np

model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')

img_path = 'elephant.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)
```

Is there any documentation with a good explanation of these functions?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py#L72

Comment: Thanks!, so I understand it normalized the pixels between -1 to +1, Any explanation on why do we have to do np.expand_dims(x, axis=0) on the input passed to this function?

Comment: @AKSHAYAAVAIDYANATHAN Sorry for the (maybe) silly question, but how do you understand that it normalized the pixels in [-1,1] from the link above?

Comment: @RicS By directly looking at the output array after using the preprocess_input() function.

Comment: @AKSHAYAAVAIDYANATHAN It was silly indeed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Keras works with batches of images. So, the first dimension is used for the number of samples (or images) you have.

When you load a single image, you get the shape of one image, which is `(size1,size2,channels)`.

In order to create a batch of images, you need an additional dimension: `(samples, size1,size2,channels)`

The `preprocess_input` function is meant to adequate your image to the format the model requires.

Some models use images with values ranging from 0 to 1. Others from -1 to +1. Others use the "caffe" style, that is not normalized, but is centered.

From the [source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py#L72), Resnet is using the caffe style.

You don't need to worry about the internal details of `preprocess_input`. But ideally, you should load images with the keras functions for that (so you guarantee that the images you load are compatible with `preprocess_input`).

Comment: Yes, but sometimes, the function is explicitly declared in the model's file, and sometimes loaded from `imagenet_utils`. See this model using a different function: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/inception_v3.py/#L391

Comment: The end users should load it from the model's module to make sure the right function is loaded.

Comment: yes Thanks again. I also see the same function for different models. For instance, there is one for vgg16, resnet50 etc. Up untill now I thought all these models actually work on images with any range. Do you think the performance of the models will be affected if I donot use their corresponding preprocess_input() method?

Comment: Yes, the performance will change. The model's weights are adapted and optimized to certain input values.

Comment: @DanielMöller Hi Daniel, you said that different models (e.g. ResNet, Xception..) use values with different ranges. How do you understand which is this range? I cannot understand it from the 'source code' link you posted in the answer.

Comment: When you import `preprocess_input` from the correct module (the module of the selected model, such as `from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input`, you have the function that properly transforms a standard image into an appropriate input. I also don't know which model uses what, but we can always take a look at the source code. If the model is custom (not pretrained), you can use any kind of input you want.

Answer (score 26):

This loads an image and resizes the image to (224, 224):

```
 img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
```

The img_to_array() function adds channels: `x.shape = (224, 224, 3)` for RGB and `(224, 224, 1)` for gray image

```
 x = image.img_to_array(img)
```

`expand_dims()` is used to add the number of images: `x.shape = (1, 224, 224, 3)`:

```
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
```

preprocess_input subtracts the mean RGB channels of the imagenet dataset. This is because the model you are using has been trained on a different dataset: `x.shape` is still `(1, 224, 224, 3)`

```
x = preprocess_input(x)
```

If you add `x` to an array `images`, at the end of the loop, you need to add `images = np.vstack(images)` so that you get `(n, 224, 224, 3)` as the dim of images where `n` is the number of images processed

Comment: I think adding images to a list and then stacking them would be more efficient that using `np.vstack()`

Answer (score 6):

I found that preprocessing your data while yours is a too different dataset vs the pre_trained model/dataset, then it may harm your accuracy somehow. If you do transfer learning and freezing some layers from a pre_trained model/their weights, simply /255.0 your original dataset does the job just fine, at least for large 1/2 millions samples food dataset. Ideally you should know your std/mean of you dataset and use it instead of using std/mdean of the pre-trained model preprocess.

Comment: Yes. A good option would be to try the default preprocess function obtained along with the model. For some models, accuracy is hit. Use the altenative suggested by Steve for such cases..This is helpful when creating ensembles

Comment: Any idea on why should the accuracy decrease with preprocessing ? I am facing the issue with transfer learning using ResNet50 pre-trained model .

Answer (score 0):

As you can see there [tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py) main purpose of preprocessing for torch is normalizing the color channels accordingly which dataset used the train the networks before. Like we do by simply (Data - Mean) / Std

Source code:

```
def _preprocess_numpy_input(x, data_format, mode):
  """Preprocesses a Numpy array encoding a batch of images.
  Arguments:
      x: Input array, 3D or 4D.
      data_format: Data format of the image array.
      mode: One of "caffe", "tf" or "torch".
          - caffe: will convert the images from RGB to BGR,
              then will zero-center each color channel with
              respect to the ImageNet dataset,
              without scaling.
          - tf: will scale pixels between -1 and 1,
              sample-wise.
          - torch: will scale pixels between 0 and 1 and then
              will normalize each channel with respect to the
              ImageNet dataset.
  Returns:
      Preprocessed Numpy array.
  """
  if mode == 'tf':
    x /= 127.5
    x -= 1.
    return x

  if mode == 'torch':
    x /= 255.
    mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
    std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
  else:
    if data_format == 'channels_first':
      # 'RGB'->'BGR'
      if x.ndim == 3:
        x = x[::-1, ...]
      else:
        x = x[:, ::-1, ...]
    else:
      # 'RGB'->'BGR'
      x = x[..., ::-1]
    mean = [103.939, 116.779, 123.68]
    std = None

  # Zero-center by mean pixel
  if data_format == 'channels_first':
    if x.ndim == 3:
      x[0, :, :] -= mean[0]
      x[1, :, :] -= mean[1]
      x[2, :, :] -= mean[2]
      if std is not None:
        x[0, :, :] /= std[0]
        x[1, :, :] /= std[1]
        x[2, :, :] /= std[2]
    else:
      x[:, 0, :, :] -= mean[0]
      x[:, 1, :, :] -= mean[1]
      x[:, 2, :, :] -= mean[2]
      if std is not None:
        x[:, 0, :, :] /= std[0]
        x[:, 1, :, :] /= std[1]
        x[:, 2, :, :] /= std[2]
  else:
    x[..., 0] -= mean[0]
    x[..., 1] -= mean[1]
    x[..., 2] -= mean[2]
    if std is not None:
      x[..., 0] /= std[0]
      x[..., 1] /= std[1]
      x[..., 2] /= std[2]
  return x
```