# preprocess_input() method in Keras with 3D input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555829/preprocess-input-method-in-keras/47556342) and the examples on [keras doc](https://keras.io/api/applications/), the preferred way is to pass a 4D array where the 1st dimension refers to the batch size.

```
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)
```

But the comments in the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/bc89834ed36935ab4a4994446e34ff81c0d8e1b7/keras_applications/imagenet_utils.py#L18) explain that it's possible to pass either a 3D or 4D array. Does this mean that I can pass a single 3D image?

```
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
#x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)
```

Comment: please add your code to the question

Comment: @Andrey Yeah sure I've added two examples to the question.